# How to programatically set entries of spinner in android?

Tags: android

I have made various string-arrays in the string.xml file and I have to set different arrays as entries for the spinner according to certain condition in Java. Is it possible or is database the only way to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use an adapter and populate with tha array in xml file.

Specify the name of your array in xml at *createFromResource* method (second parameter).

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.my_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);   
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: my data is in string.xml file. how do i get it to java to populate it?

Comment: You can do it directly with my answer. See *createFromResource* method in first line

Answer (score 8):

You have to extract your data from file:

```
String[] testArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
```

Then, you have to inflate in the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, testArray );
mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can start with using `ArrayAdapter`, it is a simple class to populate spinner items programmatically.

```
String data[];
//... do your stuff to get populate this array
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

You can also modify the view of dropdown items and customize them further by overriding this class.

Comment: but my data is in strings.xml file. How do i get it to the String arrray in java

Comment: use context class method `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array)` to get strings array