# Android Spinner fill with object

Tags: java, android

How can I fill a spinner with an Object.

Example: I have User object userId, userName, firstName, lastName. I need to fill display spinner with firstName. If user select I need to get userId.

```
    private void fillUserSpinner() {
            spinnerUserList = findViewById(R.id.spinnerUserList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, userDbHelp.gteUserIds());
            spinnerUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


    private void onUserSelected() {
            spinnerUserList = findViewById(R.id.spinnerUserList);
            spinnerUserList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
//Need to get selected userId
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: show what you tried ?

Comment: Have tried creating POJO for your details. Create one and customise ArrayAdapter for setting values for spinner. You can refere here 
https://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically set entries of spinner in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809942/how-to-programatically-set-entries-of-spinner-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You want display firstname alone, add this code into your model class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName;
}
```

Comment: You can just use getter, user.getName();

Answer (score 0):

use [AppCompatSpinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner) together with an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) ...
on case the items (POJO) of that `ArrayAdapter` override method `toString()`, one can skip manual assignment; that text is being displayed for the spinner's items then.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.firstName;
}
```